# Set Powershell title during log tailing

Tags: powershell, tail

Need to set the powershell title while opening the log tailing. I have the working scripts of each step, however its not working while clubbing together.

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Server1 - Test.log"

Get-Content "\\server1\Test.log" -tail 10 –Wait
```

Each line works individually but not together. Please share any steps to solve this.

I am getting this error [image]

Comment: It got worked with this https://forum.bigfix.com/t/tip-when-you-dont-have-tail/34553/2

Comment: The moment I execute line 1, my title changes. What is shown here works. The problem is in code that is not shown. (Or you execute them in the wrong order.)

Comment: @T-Me you mean the above script worked for you?

Comment: Yep. In Powershell and ISE.

Comment: @T-Me I updated the error I got when I use the script in the question

Comment: Created a .ps1 with the codeblock in the question. Executed it from RMB context menu> execute with powershell and opened an empty powershell and executed the script from there. The title got changed every time. Powershell 5.1. Could you test it on an other machine? Could it be a problem with the encoding of the script? The Error you get is very strange aswell...

Comment: You are executing in the shown order right? If you `-Wait` first the script will stop executing the next command. If you try to change the title later the script wont reach that point...